# ¿Error al declarar esta varible?

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

Buen día quiero declarar esto pero me sale que el tipo fecha es ambiguo a que se debe que se genere este error?

```
Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: [43] The type Date is ambiguous
40:             mes=Integer.parseInt(fecha.substring(3, 5))-1;
41:             anio=Integer.parseInt(fecha.substring(6, 10));
42:    
43:         startDate: new Date(anio, mes, dia);
44:         endDate: new Date(anio, mes, dia);
```

Comment: Hola, veo que quieres convertir una cadena a fecha, te recomendaría usar `split()`, en lugar de usar `substring` es muchísimo mejor

Answer (score 0):

En tu código hay algunos errores de sintaxis en cuanto al uso de `parseInt`.

Además, si tienes una cadena de fecha en este formato: `16-04-2018`, conviene el uso de `split` para obtener los diferentes elementos que serán parte de la fecha.

Aquí te muestro dos formas de crear un objeto `Date` válido:

```js
/* Variables con las que vamos a trabajar */
var fecha = "16-04-2018";
var arrFecha = fecha.split("-");
var yyyy  = parseInt(arrFecha[2]);
var mm    = parseInt(arrFecha[1]) - 1;
var dd    = parseInt(arrFecha[0]);

/* Forma 1: */
var starDate = new Date(yyyy, mm, dd);
alert("Start: " + starDate);

/* Forma 2: */
const [dia, mes, anio] = fecha.split("-");
var endDate = new Date(anio, mes - 1, dia);
alert("End: " + endDate);
```